# Neo4j Browser issues in Chrome and Opera

Tags: google-chrome, neo4j, opera

Noe4j 2.0.3, Community Edition, Windows 8.1 Update 1 x64.

**Chrome** *35.0.1916.114 m (at the moment)*

A little while ago, Neo4j stopped executing queries via Chrome - well, it executes every other one, so I can type:

```
MATCH n RETURN count(n)
```

press `ENTER` and get no response, press `Up Arrow` and then `ENTER` again and I'll get the results, sometimes I have to do the `Up Arrow, Enter` thing a couple of times. By no response I mean the text disappears, but no results show.

When it fails, it puts this into the console:

```
Error: Invalid value for <svg> attribute preserveAspectRatio="xMidyMid"
```

**Opera** *12.17*

Opera generally executes all queries with no problems, but will *not* save queries, so say for example I'm putting:

```
//Get Count
MATCH n RETURN count(n)
```

in the query box and then pressing the 'save' star, the star will highlight, but do nothing, a full <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> doesn't show the saved query, and so far the only way I've managed to save a query has been by dragging a file to the favourites bar.

Opera gives this error when opening Neo4j, but doesn't actually give any errors when pressing 'Save':

```
Uncaught exception: Error: WRONG_ARGUMENTS_ERR Error thrown at line 121, column 2 in getStyles(elem) in http://localhost:7474/browser/scripts/components.js:
return window.getComputedStyle(elem, )
```

**Other browsers**

I find IE11 and Firefox to both work fine (which means I *do* have a workaround) but Chrome used to work just fine until relatively recently.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you can download the latest version 2.1.1, I think everything'll work fine

Comment: Alas, no, 2.1.1 has the same problem in Chrome & Opera